# TeX/LaTeX macro to find out where am I in a tabular

Tags: tables, macros

Do you know a macro/command which can tell me where was it called in a tabular environment? Specially, i wish a macro which executes `\commandA` if I called it in the first cell of a row (or after a `\\` new line) and executes `\commandB` if I called it in the 2nd, 3rd... last cell?

Comment: The `spreadtab` package may provide such features

Comment: Related: [Row/column indexing using `collcell`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335981/5764)

Answer (score 1):

The `tabstackengine` package can produce some types of tabulars, but not all.  It cannot employ `|` column-line specifiers, and can only use `l`, `c`, and `r` column types.

But if your problem falls in this sub-category, then the counter `TABcolindex@` in the package provides the current column, which can be used to make choices in the typesetting of a column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[TABcline]{tabstackengine}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\colcheck{\theTABcolindex@}
\newcommand\colcheckA{\ifnum\theTABcolindex@=1First Column\else Other Column\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tabularCenterstack{cccc}{
 \colcheck& \colcheck& \colcheck& \colcheck\\
 \colcheck& \colcheck& \colcheck& \colcheck
}

\tabularShortstack{cccc}{
 \TABcline{1-4}
 \colcheckA& \colcheckA& \colcheckA& \colcheckA\\
 \TABcline{1-4}
 \colcheckA& \colcheckA& \colcheckA& \colcheckA\\
 \TABcline{1-4}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]